# Filter out objects from union type with any keys other than a known key

Tags: typescript

Given a type like

```
type Test = { name: "a" } | { name: "b" } | { name: "c", other: 1 } | { name: "d", other: 2 }
```

How can I filter out any types from the union that contain a key other than "name". So in this case, the resulting type would be { name: "a" } | { name: "b" }.

Here is a TS Playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwoF4oG8oDsCGBbCAXFAETbFQC+UAPulnoSQEblW0Y75HEDGxANFAD2wABYQATkQCMlGnU6NiAEwHCxkogCZKAKF2hIUAGIBLADbBJEZXEQoo2TCH3mISAB5Ezl67YRIqBwM3HyCIuJSULJUAPSxUACiEhJCErpuSCDeFlYSNnaBCiEkZHLxJqaYEEA

Comment: [This approach](https://tsplay.dev/WvkJYw) would be how I'd implement given your question but I'm curious about edge cases; what should `Filter<{name: "a"} | {name: 123} | { [k: \`na${string}\`]: "c" } | {oops: "d"} | {}>` be?  I'll write up an answer if my implementation meets your needs.  If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz - Good old edge cases. :-) Is it even possible to do this with that type? The `| {}` at the end seems to turn off excess property checks (https://tsplay.dev/ND8M8N).

Comment: For my particular case, it can be assumed that every type conforms to `{ name: string }`. We are just looking to filter out anything that may have something extra beyond just that field.

Comment: ... okay, so does [my implementation](https://tsplay.dev/WvkJYw) meet your needs or not?  Should I write up an answer or am I missing something about the question?

Comment: Yep, your answer is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general approach to something like this is to write a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) to split the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) input type up into its members and keep or discard each member individually, which will then be joined back up into another union.  Here's one possibility:

```
type Filter<T> = T extends unknown ?
    Exclude<keyof T, "name"> extends never ? T : never
    : never
```

So `T extends unknown ? ⋯ : never` distributes over unions in the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter `T`.  The particular filter I use is `Exclude<keyof T, "name"> extends never ? T : never`.  [The `Exclude<X, Y>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers) removes union members of `X` matching `Y`, so `Exclude<keyof T, "name">` is the union of keys of `T` that are not `name`.  If that union is empty (a.k.a., [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type)), then we want to keep `T`; otherwise we discard it.

Okay, let's test it out:

```
type Test = { name: "a" } | { name: "b" } |
{ name: "c", other: 1 } | { name: "d", other: 2 }

type FilteredTest = Filter<Test>;
/* type FilteredTest = { name: "a"; } | { name: "b"; } */

let x: FilteredTest = { name: "c", other: 1 } // Error
let y: FilteredTest = { name: "a" } // Fine
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAYgSwDYigJwDwBUB8MC8MWMUAHqgHYAmAzjAK4UDWFA9gO4UwD8wM-MAKKkAxknpUoGJlDCsAZkQA0MAEQUAhgFsoqvGUq0YFKADd0PIjABcxs+j4DbJ82mDvw0IlBogCMAG9jbShbVQ1VGABfGAAfQOCdMIAjSJjY4CDNJLURVRVWEAALdFsARmi4hOzQtSp8mEKStFsAJmiPSFhEFHQoKiwfP0Ie1ExB3xwAbmAAegAqGE9u5DH+ieHqkLCIqcr4rO21VL2Y+dn3JCg-UltRvoGh-0Oc1TyC4tKYCpjZ2aE0GhWG4rn4wHdVg8Ns9ErVwmkYH94AgTEA)